# How to hide one 'p' in a form with many with jQuery?

Tags: jquery

I'm simply trying to delete the 'or' through jQuery (can't edit the HTML). The 'or' is contained in a p, where there are multiple p's on the same page. I keep trying to do class selectors and using 'not' but nothing is working as expected... any idea how to solve this?

https://jsfiddle.net/8Lf97ht4/

HTML

```
<div class="snax-media-upload-form" id="snax-media-upload-form-1">
    <script type="text/javascript">
        (function(ctx) {
            if (!ctx.snaxPluploadConfig) {
                ctx.snaxPluploadConfig = {};
            }
            ctx.snaxPluploadConfig['snax-media-upload-form-1'] = {"runtimes":"html5,flash,silverlight,html4","file_data_name":"async-upload","url":"https:\/\/example.com\/wp-admin\/async-upload.php","flash_swf_url":"https:\/\/example.com\/wp-includes\/js\/plupload\/plupload.flash.swf","silverlight_xap_url":"https:\/\/example.com\/wp-includes\/js\/plupload\/plupload.silverlight.xap","filters":{"mime_types":[{"title":"Image files","extensions":"jpg,jpeg,png,gif"}],"image_max_file_size":"2097152"},"multipart_params":{"post_id":0,"_wpnonce":"5bde1ca033","short":true,"snax_media_upload_action":"new_post_upload","snax_media_upload_format":"link"},"multi_selection":false};
        })(window);
    </script>

    <div class="snax-plupload-upload-ui drag-drop" style="position: relative;">
    <div class="snax-drag-drop-area" style="position: relative;">
        <div class="snax-drag-drop-inside">
            <div class="snax-drag-drop-info-area g1-gamma g1-gamma-1st">
                <p class="snax-drag-drop-info">Drop thumbnail here</p>
            </div>
            <p>or</p>

            <p class="snax-drag-drop-buttons">
                <input type="button" value="Browse files" class="snax-plupload-browse-button g1-button g1-button-s g1-button-simple" style="z-index: 1;">
                                <input type="button" value="Get image from URL" class="snax-load-form-button g1-button g1-button-s g1-button-simple" data-snax-rel-class="snax-load-image-from-url-area">
                                            </p>
        </div>
    </div>
<div id="html5_1edkvockf1c38ok91tqq4881stb5_container" class="moxie-shim moxie-shim-html5" style="position: absolute; top: 0px; left: 0px; width: 0px; height: 0px; overflow: hidden; z-index: 0;"><input id="html5_1edkvockf1c38ok91tqq4881stb5" type="file" style="font-size: 999px; opacity: 0; position: absolute; top: 0px; left: 0px; width: 100%; height: 100%;" accept="image/jpeg,.jpg,.jpeg,image/png,.png,image/gif,.gif"></div></div>

<p class="hide-if-js">
    You don't have javascript enabled. Media upload is not possible.</p>

<div class="snax-load-image-from-url-area">
    Get image from URL  <input type="text" class="snax-load-image-from-url" size="255" placeholder="http://">
        <input type="button" value="Back" class="snax-load-form-button g1-button g1-button-s g1-button-simple" data-snax-rel-class="snax-load-image-from-url-area">
</div>

<p class="snax-max-upload-size">
    Maximum upload file size: 2 MB.</p>

    </div>
```

jQuery

```
$(document).ready(function () {
                

//      $("p.snax-drag-drop-inside").not(".snax-max-upload-size").html('');
        $("p.snax-drag-drop-inside").html('');
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do use the (`+`) selector. This will select the elements that are immediately after the specified element.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".g1-gamma-1st + p").html('');
});
```

Comment: Thanks. Is there a reverse of this like a minus selector?

Answer (score 1):

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    $('p.snax-drag-drop-info').css("display", "none");

});
```